# Is there a way I can extract numbers from a string surrounded by differing amounts zeros on both sides?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have to extract a dollar amount from one column of a csv. The dollar amount is surrounded by zeros.

### Dollars

```
1.   0000000000565400.60000000008289.116000 
2.   0000000466175218.82000043978794.228000
3.   0000000000005720.77000000000198.431000
```

From these three lines, I'd be looking to pull `565400.60, 466175218.82, 5720.77`. I don't want/care about the `8289.116, 43978794.228, 198.431`.

The `dtype` is a non-null object. I've tried converting it to a string and extracting the first 20 characters. I've also tried replacing several zeros with nothing. Obviously I can't get rid of all the zeros because of numbers like `565400.60` where I need the zeros. Even if I could get it converted to a dtype I wanted, I would have no idea how to pull the differing amounts of zeros.

```
dollars = str(dollars)
dollars = dollars.str.replace('0000000000','')

grab = dollars['Dollars'].astype(str).str[0:20]
```

Expected:

```
Dollars
------------
1. 565400.60
2. 466175218.82
3. 5720.77
```

Some of my errors:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: This is tricky. What will you expect for `0000000000123456010000111111`? `0000000000123456001000111111`? `0000000000123456000100111111`? What is clear rule how to distinguish previous number from next?

Comment: Is this a fixed length record format? ie. `Decimal(line[:19])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `pandas` solution to your problem might look something like:

```
>>> dollars = pd.Series(['0000000000565400.60000000008289.116000',
...                      '0000000466175218.82000043978794.228000',
...                      '0000000000005720.77000000000198.431000'])
>>> dollars.str[:19].astype(float).astype(str)
0        565400.6
1    466175218.82
2         5720.77
dtype: object
>>>
```

Comment: This one worked! I used  g['Dollars'] = g['Dollars'].astype('|S') to cast it as a string of the longest length, and then used your line and it did it. Thank you so much! Seriously a huge help to my team and me.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html) to index using the position of the first `.`:

```
s = '0000000000565400.60000000008289.116000 '
s[:s.index('.')+3]
# '565400.60'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try some `regex` and `.str.extract` on the series:

```
df.Dollars.str.extract(r'0+(\d+\.\d\d)')
```

Output:

```
    0
0   565400.60
1   466175218.82
2   5720.77
```

Or if you like the other part as well:

```
df.Dollars.str.extractall(r'0+(\d+\.\d\d)0+(\d+\.\d+)$'))
```

output:

```
                    0                1
  match                               
0 0         565400.60      8289.116000
1 0      466175218.82  43978794.228000
2 0           5720.77       198.431000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something along the lines of:

Search for first non-zero character index (i0).

Search for first . index (i1).

Number you want = string[i0: i1+3]

^This is all pythonic - +3 b.c. +1 extra, and 2 digits for the cents which seems to be what you want. This also assumes you always want the first number only.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, you want first number up to dot and two digits after. Then:

```
i = grab.find('.')
if i >= 0:
    grab = grab[:i + 3].lstrip('0')
```

will produce what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should find *all* your numbers just fine - caveat: only 2 decimals possible due to fixed position after `.` for 1st number:

```
text = """
0000000000565400.60000000008289.116000
0000000466175218.82000043978794.228000
0000000000005720.77000000000198.431000
"""

for line in text.split(): 
    a = (line[:line.index(".")+3])  # find first ., take 2 digits after
    b = float(line[len(a):])        # take remainder after first find and conver to float
    a = float(a)                    # convert a to float (needed string for len())
    print(a,b)
```

Output:

```
565400.6 8289.116
466175218.82 43978794.228
5720.77 198.431
```

Comment: Apparently OP just wants the first value in each line

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in string 'find' function, then subset the string given the position of the first decimal point (plus two positions for cents).  Then cast it as an integer or float, however you'd like:

```
s = '00000123000.0000123000.000'
pos = s.find('.')
number = float(s[:pos+2])
```

This should work so long as your objects are strings or can be cast as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks suspiciously like a fixed length record format, which means you can use string subscripts to get at the raw data:

```
>>> line = '0000000000565400.60000000008289.116000'
>>> first_number = line[:20]  # or :19 if you only want 2 digits after the dot
>>> first_number
'0000000000565400.600'
```

Since you're working with money amounts, the `decimal.Decimal` class is good to use for extracting the amount:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(first_number)
Decimal('565400.600')
```

if you need it as a string, then it's simply:

```
>>> str(Decimal(first_number))
'565400.600'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that the amounts are in dollars and cents, you know that you have two decimal places.  Simply grab that much of the input line and strip off the extra zeroes.

```
line = "1.   0000000000565400.60000000008289.116000"
float_pair = line.split()[1]
decpt = float_pair.find('.')
amt_str = float_pair[:dec_pt+3]   # one extra for the decimal point
amt_no_zero = amt_str.lstrip('0')
```

Result:

```
dec_pt = 16
amt_no_zero = '565400.60'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex with a pattern something like ^0+(\d+.\d{2})0+ (assuming it's always two numbers after the decimal). You can test the pattern on https://regex101.com/. Here's the code:

```
import re

string = ['0000000000565400.60000000008289.116000',
          '0000000466175218.82000043978794.228000',
          '0000000000005720.77000000000198.431000']

pattern = r'0+(?P<first_number>\d+.\d{2})0+'
for line in string:
    matches = re.search(pattern, str(line))
    print(matches['first_number'])


# 565400.60
```

Also if you're working with a block of text:

```
string = '''0000000000565400.60000000008289.116000\n
          0000000466175218.82000043978794.228000\n
          0000000000005720.77000000000198.431000\n'''

pattern = r'0+(\d+.\d{2})0+'
matches = re.findall(pattern, string, re.DOTALL)
print(matches)

# ['565400.60', '466175218.82', '5720.77']
```

Comment: Random nitpick: it's kinda weird to use both `\d` and `[0-9]` in the same pattern.

Comment: Oh, hah yeah fair point. I had it as [1-9] while I was working it out and just never noticed.